# Informix ODBC Connection Help

Tags: .net, odbc, informix

I have a development project that requires us to be able to support informix data sources via ODBC. I've downloaded the prebuilt Informix Virtual Appliance from the IBM website and am able see the server with the built in tools, but haven't been able to get at it from an ODBC connection on the client!

I have the ODBC support package installed also, and know that the driver is installed.

I've never really worked with Informix, so I don't know if there's some trick to it that I am missing, but if anyone has any suggestions, I'll take 'em.

Comment: As a general rule, it is worth quoting the exact versions of the (Informix) software you are using.  For example, IDS 11.50.TC3DE and ClientSDK 3.50.TC3DE might be the versions on the appliance you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the Informix ConnectionStrings on my favorite site for such references:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/informix

OleDb:

```
Provider=Ifxoledbc;Data Source=dbName@serverName;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

OleDb with security info in the connection string:

```
Provider=Ifxoledbc;Data Source=dbName@serverName;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Persist Security Info=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of questions; probably no actual answer, but something may jog your thoughts into finding an answer.

- Are you logged in as 'developer'?  Or as some other user - and if so, which one?
- If you say '.NET', presumably you have a Windows-based VM (that is, it is IDS running in a Windows environment, regardless of where the VMware image is itself running).
- Do you have a '.odbc.ini' file, or are you using DSN-less connections as in David Stratton's answer?
- Have you looked at SETNET32?  (On second thoughts, maybe you don't want to; but it is sometimes a part of the solution to problems on Windows - it sets the environment for the Windows connections to Informix DBMS.)
- Can you show us the minimal code and strings that you are using to connect?  Don't show an actual password!
- Have you tried compiling and running any of the demos from $INFORMIXDIR/demo?